# Google Maps for iOS, swift - How to show entire polyline between markers?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-polyline

I am trying to fit a polyline in the google map view. The polyline was acquired through overview_polyline in the google maps directions api.

Wondering how I would be able to convert an encoded polyline into something that can be worked with. I need to fit the polyline in the map view. All i have found out to do is fit the bounds to show all markers but not showcase the entire polyline.

```
func fitAllMarkers()
{

    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()

    for marker in markers
    {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }

    googleMapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds))

}
```

Comment: anybody have any advice? still haven't been able to locate a solution for the GMSPolyline

Comment: So you want to fit complete polyline in screen or you want to show perfect polyline on road?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Swift 2.0 Google Maps, to make your map view fit the polyline of the route you are drawing:

```
let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!
    routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    routePolyline.map = mapView


    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()

    for index in 1...path.count() {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(path.coordinateAtIndex(index))
    }

    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds))
```

Comment: I appreciate the update greatly! Code works perfectly. I have one question though, Do you know how to possibly size the polyline to fit within a certain region of the screen. Example: Zoom into the polyline but the polyline is centered with 20 pts of space from the top and bottom of the screen? Thanks Again! :)

Comment: Hello! I needed to do the same thing but for now I could only resize the mapView's constraints to fit the region of the screen I wanted it to cover, then applied this "fitBounds" function. (Resizing it again to full screen after fittingBounds does not work).

Comment: for swift 4, changed to bounds.includingCoordinate(path.coordinate(at: index))

Answer (score 11):

Though the question has an accepted answer,

Still one point which has not been discussed.

GMSPolyLine has a property ".path" which can used to bound the map with the complete polyline itself.

```
mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(GMSCoordinateBounds(path: self.polyLineObject.path!), withPadding: 10))
```

- mapView is an instance of GMSMapView()
- polyLineObject is an instance of GMSPolyLine()

With this approach, It'll do the job for sure.

Coz it has Done for me..

Hope it Helps..

Comment: glad I could help.!

Answer (score 2):

You can zoom the map according the route or line displayed in the mapview. So that your route is displayed with in the mapView bounds.

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path:path! )
self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50.0))
```

Here path is GMSPath of the route and mapView is GmsMapView.

Answer (score 1):

```
**For Swift 3.0 Google Maps, to make your map view fit the polyline of the route you are drawing:** 


func fitAllMarkers(_path: GMSPath) {
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        for index in 1..._path.count() {
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(_path.coordinate(at: index))
        }
        mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
    }
```