# How to draw a route between two markers in google maps (swift )?

Tags: swift, google-maps, routes, direction

I want to show direction between two markers that I had made. How can I do it? How can I show direction?

Here is my code that I used to make markers:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if counterMarker < 2
    {
        counterMarker += 1
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop

        marker.map = mapView
        marker.position.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        marker.position.longitude = coordinate.longitude

        print(marker.position.latitude)
        print(marker.position.longitude)

    }
```

And here is the code for deleting markers on click:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you Sure for deleting ?!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("No Pressed")


            })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Yes Pressed")
            marker.map = nil
            self.counterMarker -= 1

        })

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return true
    }
```

And I like to show which marker is for destination and which one is for origin.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#polylines) which allows you to draw lines on the map. You'll need to specify its path by creating a corresponding `GMSMutablePath` object with two or more points. Each `CLLocationCoordinate2D` represents a point on the Earth's surface. Line segments are drawn between points according to the order in which you add them to the path.

Example:

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))

let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
rectangle.map = mapView
```

Check these related links:

- [Drawing Route Between Two Places on GMSMapView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios)
- [Google Maps for iOS, swift - How to show entire polyline between markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095149/google-maps-for-ios-swift-how-to-show-entire-polyline-between-markers)

> For Swift 2.0 Google Maps, to make your map view fit the polyline of
>   the route you are drawing:
>
> ```
> let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!
>     routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
>     routePolyline.map = mapView
>
>
>     var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
>
>     for index in 1...path.count() {
>         bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(path.coordinateAtIndex(index))
>     }
>
>     mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds))
> ```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How can I add markers that i made by longTouch to this code? i want to add destination between that two markers .

Comment: You can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use `GMSPolyline` and set its `map` property to your `GMSMapView` to draw polyline/route on your map

Comment: how can i use it ?!

Comment: The same way you use `GMSMarker` as above.